# Choppy sound when recording sound from my microphone

Tags: linux, audio

I've just installed a fresh copy of Linux Mint 15 and so far everything is working ok, but sound from my mic. While talking on skype or just recording the sound produced is very very choppy. I tried different settings from alsamixer but couldn't fix it. Also tried searching on internet how to fix it but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

1. Fix problems with Glitches, voice skips and crackling In file /etc/pulse/default.pa its necessery to substitute the line;

load-module module-udev-detect

with

load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0

1. Resolve Choppy sound in (Pulseaudio) -> Skype

In /etc/pulse/daemon.conf two lines has to be also substituted:

; default-sample-rate = 44100

Should become;

default-sample-rate = 48000

1. Change /etc/default/pulseaudio to allow dynamic module loading

It is a good idea to the default settings from DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1 to DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0 .This step is not required and I'm not sure if it has some influence on solving sound in / out problems with Skype but I believe it can be helpful in some cases..

So in /etc/default/pulseaudio Substitute:

DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1

to;

DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0

1. Restart PulseAudio server

After the line is changed and substituted a restart of PulseAudio is required. For PulseAudio server restart a gnome session logout is necessery. Just LogOff logged Gnome user and issue cmd:

debian:~# pkill pulseaudio